# The name of a function. is it a pointer to that function?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, function-calls

When we use the name of a function to pass arguments, are we using a pointer to that function?

Example:

```
int foo(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    int a = foo(1,3); //foo() it's a pointer to the function foo()?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: NO, it is only calling the function.

Comment: Function names decay to pointers when passed as arguments. That's all you should really care about.

Comment: It does compile into a jump to the address of the code of that function so it is a pointer but that's not the usual understanding of pointers. Plus for that matter any variable could be understood to be a pointer to a space in memory

Comment: This is actually a subtle question, where the answer is more like "kind of" than "no." The machine instruction that implements the call to `foo` has an address in it or perhaps refers to a register that has the address in it. Therefore in a certain sense, the memory that holds the address (the word in the machine instruction or the register) is serving as a pointer at the machine level. However, these are not pointers in the same sense as a C variable of type `int (*)(int, int)` would be. That variable normally lives in data memory (stack or data segment).

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I was seeing the function pointers and I had this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you're looking for is *function designator*. It is not a *pointer* type, but most of the time, it is *converted* to one.

Quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.3.2.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator,65) or the unary `&` operator, **a
>   function designator with type *‘‘function returning type’’* is converted to an expression that has type *‘‘pointer to function returning type’’*.**

Related, from the "function call" part of the spec, chapter 6.5.2.2

> The expression that denotes the called function 92) shall have type pointer to function
>   returning void or returning a complete object type other than an array type.

which tells us, at the function call, the designator actually gets converted into a pointer.